# Valgrind not detecting overlapping memcpy?

Tags: c++, valgrind

I have this function which I believe has overlapping memory. Since I'm writing ahead of where I'll be reading from, it seems the `memcpy` is going to go into undefined behavior

```
void overlappingMemcpy() {
    int* data = new int[20];
    iota(data, data + 20, 1);
    printIntData(data, 20);
    memcpy(data+1, data, 19*sizeof(int));
    printIntData(data, 20);
    delete[] data;
}
```

But when it is run with Valgrind, I see no errors,

```
> valgrind --tool=memcheck  ./ValgrindExamples 
==81068== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==81068== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==81068== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==81068== Command: ./ValgrindExamples
==81068== 
Hello World!
int data for memory at 0x5b210c0of size 20
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
int data for memory at 0x5b210c0of size 20
1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 
==81068== 
==81068== HEAP SUMMARY:
==81068==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==81068==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 3 frees, 73,808 bytes allocated
==81068== 
==81068== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==81068== 
==81068== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==81068== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I'm compiling with `-O0 -g -fno-inlines -std=c++14`. The assembly shows a call to memcpy, indicating the compiler hasn't inlined it, so I'm completely lost why this isn't getting triggered. Full assembly generated of the above method,

```
        128 [1] void overlappingMemcpy() {
0x401320                   55                                            push   %rbp
0x401321  <+0x0001>        48 89 e5                                      mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x401324  <+0x0004>        48 83 ec 20                                   sub    $0x20,%rsp
0x401328  <+0x0008>        b8 50 00 00 00                                mov    $0x50,%eax
0x40132d  <+0x000d>        89 c7                                         mov    %eax,%edi
        129 [1]     int* data = new int[20];
0x40132f  <+0x000f>        e8 dc f9 ff ff                                callq  0x400d10 <_Znam@plt>
0x401334  <+0x0014>        ba 01 00 00 00                                mov    $0x1,%edx
0x401339  <+0x0019>        48 89 45 f8                                   mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
        130 [1]     iota(data, data + 20, 1);
0x40133d  <+0x001d>        48 8b 7d f8                                   mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rdi
0x401341  <+0x0021>        48 8b 45 f8                                   mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
0x401345  <+0x0025>        48 83 c0 50                                   add    $0x50,%rax
0x401349  <+0x0029>        48 89 c6                                      mov    %rax,%rsi
0x40134c  <+0x002c>        e8 cf 00 00 00                                callq  0x401420 <std::iota<int*, int>(int*, int*, int)>
0x401351  <+0x0031>        ba 14 00 00 00                                mov    $0x14,%edx
0x401356  <+0x0036>        89 d6                                         mov    %edx,%esi
        131 [1]     printIntData(data, 20);
0x401358  <+0x0038>        48 8b 7d f8                                   mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rdi
0x40135c  <+0x003c>        e8 df fb ff ff                                callq  0x400f40 <printIntData(int*, unsigned long)>
0x401361  <+0x0041>        ba 14 00 00 00                                mov    $0x14,%edx
0x401366  <+0x0046>        89 d6                                         mov    %edx,%esi
0x401368  <+0x0048>        ba 4c 00 00 00                                mov    $0x4c,%edx
        132 [1]     memcpy(data+1, data, 19*sizeof(int));
0x40136d  <+0x004d>        48 8b 45 f8                                   mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
0x401371  <+0x0051>        48 83 c0 04                                   add    $0x4,%rax
0x401375  <+0x0055>        48 8b 7d f8                                   mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rdi
0x401379  <+0x0059>        48 89 7d f0                                   mov    %rdi,-0x10(%rbp)
0x40137d  <+0x005d>        48 89 c7                                      mov    %rax,%rdi
0x401380  <+0x0060>        48 8b 45 f0                                   mov    -0x10(%rbp),%rax
0x401384  <+0x0064>        48 89 75 e8                                   mov    %rsi,-0x18(%rbp)
0x401388  <+0x0068>        48 89 c6                                      mov    %rax,%rsi
0x40138b  <+0x006b>        e8 d0 f9 ff ff                                callq  0x400d60 <memcpy@plt>
        133 [1]     printIntData(data, 20);
0x401390  <+0x0070>        48 8b 7d f8                                   mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rdi
0x401394  <+0x0074>        48 8b 75 e8                                   mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rsi
0x401398  <+0x0078>        e8 a3 fb ff ff                                callq  0x400f40 <printIntData(int*, unsigned long)>
        134 [1]     delete[] data;
0x40139d  <+0x007d>        48 8b 45 f8                                   mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
0x4013a1  <+0x0081>        48 83 f8 00                                   cmp    $0x0,%rax
0x4013a5  <+0x0085>        48 89 45 e0                                   mov    %rax,-0x20(%rbp)
0x4013a9  <+0x0089>        0f 84 0c 00 00 00                             je     0x4013bb <overlappingMemcpy()+155>
0x4013af  <+0x008f>        48 8b 45 e0                                   mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
0x4013b3  <+0x0093>        48 89 c7                                      mov    %rax,%rdi
0x4013b6  <+0x0096>        e8 05 fa ff ff                                callq  0x400dc0 <_ZdaPv@plt>
        135 [1] }
0x4013bb  <+0x009b>        48 83 c4 20                                   add    $0x20,%rsp
0x4013bf  <+0x009f>        5d                                            pop    %rbp
0x4013c0  <+0x00a0>        c3                                            retq
```

Should this not be reported by the tool? It says on the documentation page that it detects "Passes overlapping source and destination memory blocks to memcpy() and related functions."

**Edit**
Thanks to a commenter, I found that the optimized version of memcpy that appears to be called in the above assembly is redirected by Valgrind to `memmove` (at least, that's what I surmise). The verbose Valgrind run is below,

```
> valgrind -v  ./ValgrindExamples 
==56912== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==56912== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==56912== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==56912== Command: ./ValgrindExamples
==56912== 
--56912-- Valgrind options:
--56912--    -v
--56912-- Contents of /proc/version:
--56912--   Linux version 4.14.7-041407-generic (kernel@gloin) (gcc version 7.2.0 (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3)) #201712171031 SMP Sun Dec 17 15:33:35 UTC 2017
--56912-- 
--56912-- Arch and hwcaps: AMD64, LittleEndian, amd64-cx16-lzcnt-rdtscp-sse3-avx-avx2-bmi
--56912-- Page sizes: currently 4096, max supported 4096
--56912-- Valgrind library directory: /usr/lib/valgrind
--56912-- Reading syms from /home/charlie/Projects/build-ValgrindExamples-Desktop-Default/ValgrindExamples
--56912-- Reading syms from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.26.so
--56912--   Considering /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.26.so ..
--56912--   .. CRC mismatch (computed 89c8df08 wanted 47b839f9)
--56912--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.26.so ..
--56912--   .. CRC is valid
--56912-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux
--56912--   Considering /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux ..
--56912--   .. CRC mismatch (computed 9fa343a0 wanted dc854ea8)
--56912--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--56912--    object doesn't have a dynamic symbol table
--56912-- Scheduler: using generic scheduler lock implementation.
--56912-- Reading suppressions file: /usr/lib/valgrind/default.supp
==56912== embedded gdbserver: reading from /tmp/vgdb-pipe-from-vgdb-to-56912-by-charlie-on-???
==56912== embedded gdbserver: writing to   /tmp/vgdb-pipe-to-vgdb-from-56912-by-charlie-on-???
==56912== embedded gdbserver: shared mem   /tmp/vgdb-pipe-shared-mem-vgdb-56912-by-charlie-on-???
==56912== 
==56912== TO CONTROL THIS PROCESS USING vgdb (which you probably
==56912== don't want to do, unless you know exactly what you're doing,
==56912== or are doing some strange experiment):
==56912==   /usr/lib/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid=56912 ...command...
==56912== 
==56912== TO DEBUG THIS PROCESS USING GDB: start GDB like this
==56912==   /path/to/gdb ./ValgrindExamples
==56912== and then give GDB the following command
==56912==   target remote | /usr/lib/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid=56912
==56912== --pid is optional if only one valgrind process is running
==56912== 
--56912-- REDIR: 0x401f860 (ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:strlen) redirected to 0x58060901 (???)
--56912-- REDIR: 0x401f640 (ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:index) redirected to 0x5806091b (???)
--56912-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so
--56912--   Considering /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so ..
--56912--   .. CRC mismatch (computed f3fb86a7 wanted 0b99f9ab)
--56912--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--56912-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so
--56912--   Considering /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so ..
--56912--   .. CRC mismatch (computed 5ffa922b wanted 4228a583)
--56912--    object doesn't have a symbol table
==56912== WARNING: new redirection conflicts with existing -- ignoring it
--56912--     old: 0x0401f860 (strlen              ) R-> (0000.0) 0x58060901 ???
--56912--     new: 0x0401f860 (strlen              ) R-> (2007.0) 0x04c32db0 strlen
--56912-- REDIR: 0x401d8d0 (ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:strcmp) redirected to 0x4c33ee0 (strcmp)
--56912-- REDIR: 0x401fda0 (ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:mempcpy) redirected to 0x4c374f0 (mempcpy)
--56912-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.24
--56912--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--56912-- Reading syms from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.26.so
--56912--   Considering /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.26.so ..
--56912--   .. CRC mismatch (computed b616e9a5 wanted 56d31e5b)
--56912--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.26.so ..
--56912--   .. CRC is valid
--56912-- Reading syms from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
--56912--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--56912-- Reading syms from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.26.so
--56912--   Considering /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.26.so ..
--56912--   .. CRC mismatch (computed b6c34c34 wanted f79829d1)
--56912--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.26.so ..
--56912--   .. CRC is valid
--56912-- REDIR: 0x57c3f50 (libc.so.6:memmove) redirected to 0x4a2a6e0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--56912-- REDIR: 0x57c3010 (libc.so.6:strncpy) redirected to 0x4a2a6e0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--56912-- REDIR: 0x57c4230 (libc.so.6:strcasecmp) redirected to 0x4a2a6e0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--56912-- REDIR: 0x57c2a60 (libc.so.6:strcat) redirected to 0x4a2a6e0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--56912-- REDIR: 0x57c3040 (libc.so.6:rindex) redirected to 0x4a2a6e0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--56912-- REDIR: 0x57c5bb0 (libc.so.6:rawmemchr) redirected to 0x4a2a6e0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--56912-- REDIR: 0x57c40c0 (libc.so.6:mempcpy) redirected to 0x4a2a6e0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--56912-- REDIR: 0x57c3ee0 (libc.so.6:bcmp) redirected to 0x4a2a6e0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--56912-- REDIR: 0x57c2fd0 (libc.so.6:strncmp) redirected to 0x4a2a6e0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--56912-- REDIR: 0x57c2ad0 (libc.so.6:strcmp) redirected to 0x4a2a6e0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--56912-- REDIR: 0x57c4020 (libc.so.6:memset) redirected to 0x4a2a6e0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--56912-- REDIR: 0x57e1f10 (libc.so.6:wcschr) redirected to 0x4a2a6e0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--56912-- REDIR: 0x57c2f70 (libc.so.6:strnlen) redirected to 0x4a2a6e0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--56912-- REDIR: 0x57c2b40 (libc.so.6:strcspn) redirected to 0x4a2a6e0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--56912-- REDIR: 0x57c4280 (libc.so.6:strncasecmp) redirected to 0x4a2a6e0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--56912-- REDIR: 0x57c2b10 (libc.so.6:strcpy) redirected to 0x4a2a6e0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--56912-- REDIR: 0x57c43c0 (libc.so.6:memcpy@@GLIBC_2.14) redirected to 0x4a2a6e0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--56912-- REDIR: 0x57c3070 (libc.so.6:strpbrk) redirected to 0x4a2a6e0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--56912-- REDIR: 0x57c2a90 (libc.so.6:index) redirected to 0x4a2a6e0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--56912-- REDIR: 0x57c2f40 (libc.so.6:strlen) redirected to 0x4a2a6e0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--56912-- REDIR: 0x57ce510 (libc.so.6:memrchr) redirected to 0x4a2a6e0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--56912-- REDIR: 0x57c42d0 (libc.so.6:strcasecmp_l) redirected to 0x4a2a6e0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--56912-- REDIR: 0x57c3eb0 (libc.so.6:memchr) redirected to 0x4a2a6e0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--56912-- REDIR: 0x57e2cc0 (libc.so.6:wcslen) redirected to 0x4a2a6e0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--56912-- REDIR: 0x57c3350 (libc.so.6:strspn) redirected to 0x4a2a6e0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--56912-- REDIR: 0x57c4200 (libc.so.6:stpncpy) redirected to 0x4a2a6e0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--56912-- REDIR: 0x57c41d0 (libc.so.6:stpcpy) redirected to 0x4a2a6e0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--56912-- REDIR: 0x57c5be0 (libc.so.6:strchrnul) redirected to 0x4a2a6e0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--56912-- REDIR: 0x57c4320 (libc.so.6:strncasecmp_l) redirected to 0x4a2a6e0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--56912-- REDIR: 0x58ad6f0 (libc.so.6:__strrchr_avx2) redirected to 0x4c32730 (rindex)
--56912-- REDIR: 0x57bdeb0 (libc.so.6:malloc) redirected to 0x4c2faa0 (malloc)
--56912-- REDIR: 0x58ad8c0 (libc.so.6:__strlen_avx2) redirected to 0x4c32cf0 (strlen)
--56912-- REDIR: 0x58a9ed0 (libc.so.6:__memcmp_avx2_movbe) redirected to 0x4c35e00 (bcmp)
--56912-- REDIR: 0x58890b0 (libc.so.6:__strcmp_ssse3) redirected to 0x4c33da0 (strcmp)
Hello World!
--56912-- REDIR: 0x4ecc500 (libstdc++.so.6:operator new[](unsigned long)) redirected to 0x4c30830 (operator new[](unsigned long))
--56912-- REDIR: 0x58adde0 (libc.so.6:__mempcpy_avx_unaligned_erms) redirected to 0x4c37130 (mempcpy)
int data for memory at 0x5b210c0of size 20
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
--56912-- REDIR: 0x58ade00 (libc.so.6:__memcpy_avx_unaligned_erms) redirected to 0x4c366e0 (memmove)
int data for memory at 0x5b210c0of size 20
1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 
--56912-- REDIR: 0x4eca3b0 (libstdc++.so.6:operator delete[](void*)) redirected to 0x4c316d0 (operator delete[](void*))
--56912-- REDIR: 0x57be3e0 (libc.so.6:free) redirected to 0x4c30cd0 (free)
==56912== 
==56912== HEAP SUMMARY:
==56912==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==56912==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 3 frees, 73,808 bytes allocated
==56912== 
==56912== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==56912== 
==56912== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==56912== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

So the follow-up question: what is choosing to call `__memcpy_avx_unaligned_erms`, I don't see it in the assembly. Due to the occurrence of the REDIR being aligned to when the memcpy is called, it seems to me as though Valgrind has figured out something I can't see in the assembly :$

Comment: Based on the results, it looks like your `memcpy()` implementation acts like `memmove()`.

Comment: It does, I suppose another way to phrase my question is why, given that there is a call to memcpy() in the assembly, and that Valgrind intercepts such functions to check for errors, are none thrown here, when the dst and src arguments overlap?

Comment: Very strange, it definitely seems like this should be detected. I was going to ask if you have `Overlap` suppression enabled. But I see that it says "suppressed: 0". But just to be sure, try running with `-v` to see details of suppressions.

Comment: @Barmar, thank you for that suggestion, I have no suppressions, but after reading the verbose log, I do see an optimized call to memcpy being `REDIR`'d (I assume "redirected") to a call to `memmove`. I have updated my question with this new information.

Comment: valgrind detects problems that actually happened on that run,  it doesn't detect code that is UB but happened to work correctly

Comment: The advertised abilities of the memcheck tool: http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html -- explicitly it says "Overlapping src and dst pointers in memcpy and related functions." -- how could this test case be anymore obvious of an instance where overlapping memory regions are being used in memcpy?

Comment: OK; so in a callgrind there appears to be a thing called `dl-trampoline.h` that has functions like `_dl_runtime_resolve_avx_slow` just before the call to memcpy. I've no idea yet, but I'm guessing logic exists in the dynamic loader to patch out syscalls like this based on some kind of heuristics??

Comment: FYI, there's a `valgrind-users` mailing list. See http://valgrind.org/support/mailing_lists.html

Comment: OK; I will take it there, I hate mailing lists so try to resolve without needing to register them :)